# Get the first key of a javascript object

Tags: jquery, json

A very basic question, but I can't find the solution :

I have a jquery object (given in `console.log`):

```
{ 
    id_ship: "1",  
    id_company: "1",  
    code: "DE",  
    // other properties...
}
```

I just want to get the first key on the object. In this case, i want to obtain `id_ship`

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot guarantee the order of the properties of an object, therefore you cannot reliably retrieve the 'first' item.

Comment: Order is only guaranteed in arrays. Would you settle for first *alphabetically-by-property-name*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/2991525

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 20):

As @RoryMcCrossan has said, the order in object is not guranteed. But if you still want to get first key you can use:

```
Object.keys(obj)[0];
```

Comment: how if I have two object in array? when I want to get `id_ship` in the first object.. I try to use `Object.keys(obj[0])[0]` I try to console it and I got two.. how to get one?

Comment: @JamesRiady If you want to get the value of `id_ship`, you should use `arr[0].id_ship`. To get first key of first object in the array, use `Object.keys/(arr[0])[0]`.